# Git Comments Clarification

Tags: git, unix, github, aix

I have GIT set up on Aix 6.1 server and after commiting to a repository and doing a git log command I'm getting some junk in the messages being displayed as shown.

```
^[[33mcommit b2b7060558d6b7579f4f2a628f3d542d88784171^[[m
Author: user1 <user1@cc.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 15 07:14:14 2013 -0500

    Initial Commit
```

Here before the commit word there is some junk being displayed **^[[33m** and also at the end **^[[m**

Why is this junk being displayed and how can I remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminal doesn't render correctly the output colors of git. You can turn off the colorized output in git:

```
git config --global color.ui false
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess git is trying to do coloring, but your terminal isn't being very supportive.

The sequence you're seeing is a typical [ANSI select graphic rendition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) sequence, trying to change the text color (to yellow).

Comment: But I do get the red colour for unstaged files and green colour for staged files while I try the git status command.